# Text color of disabled control - how to change it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, disabled-control

During the creation of my awesome Matching Game ;) I found a problem that is completely out of reach.

When the player chooses two labels with symbols on them I want to lock all the other labels for 4 seconds.

But when I do that, the forecolor of all the labels changes to grey and the symbols are visible. My question is - is there a method to change the `ForeColor` of a disabled label in visual c#?

The project is a WinForm application.

At the moment I set the color of a label in code this way:

```
label1.ForeColor = lable1.BackColor;
```

When the user clicks the label I change it to:

```
lable1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

Comment: What project type? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: How are you setting the color at the moment? Can you post your code?

Comment: Labels are **always** "locked", at least in the sense that users can't edit their text or otherwise manipulate them. There's no need to disable them to get that effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Way* simpler than trying to change the way Windows draws disabled controls is to simply set a flag when you want the `Label` to be effectively "disabled", and then check the value of that flag in your `Click` event handler method before taking whatever action you want. If the control has been "disabled", then don't take any action.

Something like this:

```
private bool labelDisabled = false;

private void myLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!labelDisabled)
    {
        this.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
    }
}
```

Also, note that you should always use the `SystemColors` instead of something like `Color.Black`.
If you hard-code specific color values, they will often conflict when the user customizes their default Windows theme. [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/12/6648399.aspx) discusses the perils of this in an article on his blog.

Comment: Just a comment on the "always use SystemColors" advice - I'd say it should be always or never - as in, hardcode all colors for everything or none of them.  Sometimes you want to control the look of things yourself instead of being a slave to the Windows theme.  But don't mix them, that's when you get things conflicting.

Comment: Yes, definitely it's an "all or nothing" affair. But I take issue with your "slave to the Windows theme" phrasing. It helps if you think of it as "slave to your user's preferences." A rather good idea.

Answer (score 13):

Just create your own label with a redefined paint event:

```
protected override void OnPaint ( System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e )
{
    if ( Enabled )
    {
        //use normal realization
        base.OnPaint (e);
        return;
    }
    //custom drawing
    using ( Brush aBrush = new SolidBrush( "YourCustomDisableColor" ) )
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString( Text, Font, aBrush, ClientRectangle );
    }
}
```

Be careful with text format flags during text drawing.

Comment: For anybody else who tries to do this with a DateTimePicker: here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595481/datetimepicker-and-userpaint-text-and-button-missing