# Why DateTimePicker BackColor Disable manual typing?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, datetimepicker

I override OnPaint method in the aim to put color in the textbox of a DateTimePicker Control and it disable the manual typing in the textbox ?

have you some ideas to solve this problem ?

```
public class BCDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    public BCDateTimePicker() 
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Rectangle dropDownRectangle = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Width - 20, 0, 20, 20);
        Brush bkgBrush;
        ComboBoxState visualState;
        if (this.Enabled)
        {
            bkgBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            visualState = ComboBoxState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            bkgBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            visualState = ComboBoxState.Disabled;
        }
        g.FillRectangle(bkgBrush, 0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
        g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 2);
        ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(g, dropDownRectangle, visualState);

        g.Dispose();
        bkgBrush.Dispose();
    }

    [Browsable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get { return base.BackColor; }
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }

}
```

I give more details concerning "Manual typing" :
It's when you press tab and you go on the DateTimePicker. Then you can enter a new date using your keyboard.

Like that :

[image]

Comment: do you every call the overridden OnPaint method? Maybe you should rather check this method for the background painting? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaintbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Try to get help from:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30660/A-DateTimePicker-with-working-BackColor
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595481/datetimepicker-and-userpaint-text-and-button-missing

Comment: I use the link from codeproject to do my code. I justl try with the background painting but it don't work.

Comment: If i type a date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` the control displays the correct date. And then, if i click the dropdown button, the calendar correctly displays the date i just typed. So, what do you mean by "disable manual typing" ?

Comment: I call "manual typing" when you click the textbox and you enter the date with the keyboard not with the calendar

Comment: ok, that's working...

Comment: I added an animated GIF in case print screens aren't enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyboard input was not disabled, highlighting capability was, because of your simplistic `OnPaint` implementation. Initially we have:

[image]

And then clicking the control to gain focus and typing, let's say, "07/04/1776" (**IMPORTANT**: backslashes included), we get:

[image]

and finally, selecting the drop down button, just to confirm:

[image]

This is the code:

```
public class BCDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    public BCDateTimePicker()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

        Rectangle dropDownRectangle = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Width - 20, 0, 20, 20);
        Brush bkgBrush;
        ComboBoxState visualState;
        if (this.Enabled)
        {
            bkgBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            visualState = ComboBoxState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            bkgBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            visualState = ComboBoxState.Disabled;
        }
        g.FillRectangle(bkgBrush, 0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
        g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 2);
        ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(g, dropDownRectangle, visualState);

        g.Dispose();
        bkgBrush.Dispose();
    }

    [Browsable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get { return base.BackColor; }
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }
}
```

The `Form` contains a regular `DateTimePicker` and a `BCDateTimePicker`, with the green background (set through VS Designer).

So, it works as expected. The text box even updates dynamically as the date is being typed.

**EDIT 1**: This GIF was too large to upload on SO:

[See animated GIF here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANaWQ.jpg)

**EDIT 2**: Note about [ControlStyles.UserPaint - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If **true**, the control paints itself rather than the operating system doing so. If **false**, the Paint event is not raised. This style only applies to classes derived from Control.

Note that `BCDateTimePicker` lost its textbox edit-highlighting capability. That's because your implementation of `OnPaint` is way more simplistic than what is done by the operating system. But keyboard input was not disabled and is still operational.

Comment: Is there a way to make text highlighted?